# Can I make nativescript $navigateTo return a promise?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Here is my method that handles submission of the OTP:

```
      submitOTP() {
        const loader = new LoadingIndicator();
        loader.show({
          message: 'Verifying your response...',
          dimBackground: true,
          userInteractionEnabled: false, // default true. Set false so that the touches will fall through it.
          hideBezel: true, // default false, can hide the surrounding bezel
          mode: Mode.Indeterminate, // see options below
        });
        this.$store
          .dispatch('submitOTP', this.otp)
          .then(stt => {
            if (stt == 'signed up') {
              this.$navigateTo(RegistrationForm, {clearHistory: true});
            } else if (stt == 'signed in') {
              this.$navigateTo(Home, {clearHistory: true});
            }
            loader.hide();
          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
            loader.hide();
          });
      },
```

The problem this has is that the loading indicator gets hidden and after than a second is taken and then the new page is loaded. I was wondering if I could do something like this:

```
this.$navigateTo(Home, {clearHistory: true}).then(loader.hide())
```

Comment: Obviously the page you are navigating to is doing a log of work on its initial load ()I am guessing it is fetching data async) SO why not placing a loader on the landing page (which should be closed once the data is loaded and the UI is ready for visualization). Using promise won't resolve you issue if the landing page still needs to take a second to fetch the data.

Comment: @NickIliev It's creating the UI that takes time. Fetching the data happens inside the submitOTP action.

Comment: So the home page is just UI and no async tasks in the code-behind? If that is the case, your Home page must have some kind o issue - 1 whole second is too much for a UI to render.